# When I get the file from s3 bucket, i can download in html page, but unable to view the pdf file

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I want to view the pdf file from S3 bucket in html using iframe/embed tag.

Answer (score 1):

I got the result, in iframe tag
src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=/path to file/filename.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"